# What did I do wrong with my Rails migrations for Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-migrations

I'm trying to add my `Address` table's `text` property as the `address` property of my `Brewery` table, then delete the `Address` table.  I'm doing this on Heroku after a `git push heroku master` by running `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

My first migration which creates the new field for the data works fine.  But my second migration fails immediately- it says it can't find the `Address` table.  My third migration never runs, but it's the one that was supposed to delete the `Address` table to tidy everything up.

What am I doing wrong?  These migrations worked on my local box, but are failing on Heroku:

## 1:

```
class AddAddressStringToBrewery < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :breweries, :address, :string
  end
end
```

## 2:

```
class MoveAddressToString < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    Address.all.each do |address|
      brewery = address.brewery
      brewery.update(address: address.text)
    end
  end
end
```

## 3:

```
class DropAddressTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :addresses
  end
end
```

My best guess is that Heroku is reading my schema and dropping the table, before running my migrations.  I could always stage these migrations in individual git commits to force it to work, but I'd really like to know where I went wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: So your ultimate goal is to drop the `addresses` table? Why do the other migrations matter in that case?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to migrate the data out of the addresses table before deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what I did wrong.  My push to Heroku with these migrations also deleted my Address model.  When I ran them in my local environment it was before I cleaned up the old Address code.  I added the Address model back long enough to run the migrations and they all run fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the file names of your migrations are in the wrong order. Rails will migrate files based on the timestamp of the file name. So if you want #2 to run before #3, you have to rename it to a file name timestamp that comes before #3.

Also, you don't show the migration which creates the Address table. The table may not be in your production database.

Answer (score 0):

Try `heroku run rake db:migrate` to update your production database.

Comment: That's what I did.  I updated my question to clarify that.  My problem is my second migration failed immediately because my address table was gone.  That shouldn't have happened until migration #3.

Comment: Ahh, on a closer look I see you are using the Address model in your second migration. Did you also destroy the model after dropping the table on local? If so, that migration would now fail because there is no Address in your files.